# VMware 2.0.2 on Windows Server 2008 R2 - Guest 100% CPU, Host 8%

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-server

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 on 64bit machine with 16 GB RAM and 2 x E5620 CPUs. This host running VMware 2.0.2 with 5 guests:

- 3 x Windows 2008
- 2 x Windows 2000 (after p2v - VMware convertor)

they all configured to use 1 CPU (not specified one.)

They are all using maximum of ~500 Mhz. For example, my Windows 2000 CPU reach 100% without effecting the host CPU, I mean when the guest CPU is 100% - it's using 284 Mhz of the host while the host CPU usage is 10% (generally, when I check at task manager).

Operating system use uniprocess without any hidden devices at device manager.

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, but what is the problem?

Comment: Why VMWARE SERVER not increasing the CPU resources for this Guest? there is free resources on the host and i didn't set such limit.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the VMware Server documentation](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmserver2.pdf) Windows Server 2008 R2 is not a supported operating system. It's not surprising that you're experiencing performance issues.

You shouldn't be using VMware Server anywhere. It was end of general support on 6/30/2011. It's dead, let it die. If you have Windows Server 2008 R2 and need to run Windows on the host for some reason, consider the using Hyper-V role. If you can use a bare-metal hypervisor, I'd recommend using the standalone Hyper-V Server of the free VMware ESXi.